# INSERT INTO error message

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, insert

I created a web application with Visual Web Developer in ASP.NET and a SQL Server database. In `SqlDataSource` I made connection with `INSERT INTO`.

So my code is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1]"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Name(nick)], [E-mail], [Text]) VALUES (@Name(nick), @E-mail, @Text)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name(nick)" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="E-mail" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Text" />
        </InsertParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Everything looks well without any errors. When I view my project in web browser or I start debugging I have normal web page. Then I type some text, click to send button and error in application.

> *Description: Incorrect syntax near '('. Must declare the scalar
>   variable "@Name".*
>
> *Specifications: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax
>   near '('. Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".*

In my table I have all this values and in my web page I use it as well. Could you help me what is wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replace with this query

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, E-mail, Text) VALUES (@Name, @E-mail, @Text)
```

(nick) create problem in your query

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, E-mail, Text) VALUES (@Name, @E-mail, @Text)">
```

Comment: Now it looks well but I have error: Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.:-) In table I use Name - nvarchar(50) Mail - nvarchar(200) Message - nvarchar(MAX)

The same values I wrote also to ViewForm...

Comment: delete also (nick) from <asp:Parameter Name="Name(nick)" />

Comment: It is done. New version is: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1]"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Name], [Mail], [Message]) VALUES (@Name, @Mail, @Message)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Mail" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Message" />
        </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: i come back user1634313 i'am sorry

Answer (score 2):

The syntax seems incorrect. 
You need to list the field names then the parameters names
I suppose the correct field is `Name` and you have a parameter called `@nick` but, as far as I know could be also the reverse.

```
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Name], [E-mail], [Text]) VALUES (@nick, @E-mail, @Text)"
```

As a side note, try to avoid to use the name of a data type (TEXT)  as field names

Comment: Well I used Name instead Name(nick) and Message instead Text and InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Name], [E-mail], [Message]) VALUES (@Name, @E-mail, @Message)"> and now I have error message Incorrect syntax near '-'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@E".

Comment: @user1634313: don't use any brackets (`(` and `)`) or dashes (`-`) or such things in your parameter names - use **just plain characters** - use `@name`, `@nickname`, `@email` (no dashes, no brackets, no "funny" stuff!)

Comment: As @marc_s said, the parameter name is an identifier for t-sql. You could find the rules to name an identifier on your Sql Books online, or at [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Parameter containing brackets `Name(nick)` is not allowed, and it is causing the problem.
Just replace it in the `InsertParameters` and in the `InsertCommand`.

```
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Name], [E-mail], [Text]) VALUES (@Name, @E-mail, @Text)">
  -- [Name] is considered as column in the table
 <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
```